# How to make default Android loader animation?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, loading

I want to make an Android "busy" animation, with similar image to default.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You didn't actually ask a question. I guess that's "How to do it?"?. Anyways, please do a little research and try to solve a problem on your own before posting here. Then post a specific question with details what exactly didn't work and what you tried. Include small code snippets, screenshots of your attempt and a description of decent length, according to what's needed *(1 sentence is usually not enough)*. Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need something like this in your Android application, you can use a `ProgressBar`. It offers a [`setIndeterminate()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29) which makes it display an infinite spinning circle (like the one in your example).

If another drawable is needed, you can use the [`setIndeterminateDrawable()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#invalidateDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

If you just want an animated image of this spinning circle (e.g. for your Ajax loading-process), you can find one here: http://www.ajaxload.info/

Answer (score 1):

Just use a static image and rotate it. This will give you the desired effect.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refreshicon);

float ROTATE_FROM = 0.0f; // from what position you want to rotate it
float ROTATE_TO = 10.0f * 360.0f; // how many times you want it to rotate in one 'animation' (in this example you want to fully rotate -360 degrees- it 10 times)

RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
r.setDuration(7500); // here you determine how fast you want the image to rotate
r.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // how many times you want to repeat the animation
r.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // the curve of the animation; use LinearInterpolator to keep a consistent speed all the way

image.startAnimation(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's FrameAnimation.

You can check this article to know how to create it: http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-make-a-loading-animator-in-android

Comment: Saidly posterous.com is no longer in business. Now we programmers suffer the cost.